# Swift 3 - Background loop not working properly

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skaction

I am trying to make a Flappy Bird like game and have to make my background loop infinitely. I found some tutorials online but it is just not working for me and I can't figure out why.

This is my code so far

```
var Background = SKSpriteNode()
var txtBG = SKTexture(imageNamed: "Background")
var txtLand = SKTexture(imageNamed: "Ground")
var Ground = SKSpriteNode()
var moving:SKNode!


// Cena

override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

    scene?.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)

    moving = SKNode()
    self.addChild(moving)


    //Ground

    Ground = SKSpriteNode(texture: txtLand)
    Ground.position = CGPoint(x:0, y: txtLand.size().height * 1.3)
    Ground.setScale(2.5)
    self.addChild(Ground)




    //Background

    Background = SKSpriteNode(texture: txtBG)
    Background.setScale(2.0)
    Background.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width, y: txtLand.size().height * 5.2 )

    let BGmove = SKAction.moveBy(x: -txtBG.size().width * 2.0, y: txtLand.size().height * 5.2 , duration: TimeInterval(15))
    let BGRepo = SKAction.moveBy(x: txtBG.size().width * 2.0, y: txtLand.size().height * 5.2, duration: 0.0)
    let BGLoop = SKAction.repeatForever(SKAction.sequence([BGmove,BGRepo]))

    for i in 0 ..< 2 + Int(self.frame.size.width / ( txtBG.size().width * 2 )) {
        let i = CGFloat(i)
        Background = SKSpriteNode(texture: txtBG)
        Background.setScale(2.0)
        Background.position = CGPoint(x:txtBG.size().width/2 + txtBG.size().width * i * 2.0, y: txtLand.size().height * 5.2)
        Background.run(BGLoop)
        self.addChild(Background)
    }
```

What happens is the background starts moving horizontally but also moving upwards and I don't understand why.

Any help will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Background Move actions have the background moving by x and by y. If you want to use `SKAction.moveBy(x: CGFloat, y: CGFloat, duration: TimeInterval)` then set y to 0 or you can use `SKAction.moveTo(x: CGFloat, duration: TimeInterval)` to only move the x value.